# Windows disabling one or more startup items

Tags: boot, windows-11, task-scheduler

I am running Windows 11 on a Dell desktop, and I want to load six programs when I start my machine. My problem is that although I have all six programs setup to load at startup, something keeps disabling one or more of them, so I only get some of them starting.

The problem seems to be confined to two programs, Start11 and 7+ Taskbar Tweaker, both run fine if I start them manually. I have tried setting them up in Task Scheduler but have had no success either.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Windows will run anything in the startup, if it exists or doesn't exist, so what is removing those entries isn't "Windows".  Have you tried to reinstall Start11?

Comment: Yes, have reinstalled Start11, and as I said it runs perfectly if started manually

Comment: Have you disabled the key that automatically starts it?  You can use a program called Autoruns to at least confirm the key exists.  Just putting Start11 in the startup folder isn't enough to automatically start an application like that.  It might be enough for 7+ Taskbar Tweaker but those two programs are vastly different.

Comment: Will have a look at that.  But it is worth noting that Start11 did run on startup once but the next time it had been disabled again.

Comment: Before or after you installed 7+ Taskbar Tweaker?

Comment: Have been testing again:

Comment: Have looked at Autoruns but wasn't sure what I was looking for.  Can't find a way to disable the key.  Have had 7+ installed for ages, well before I started using Start11.

Have been testing again:
Made sure all enabled in Task Manager/Startup
Restarted PC
7+ Taskbar Tweaker ran, Start11 didn't
Checked Task Manager/Startup, Star11 had been Disabled
Restarted PC, neither ran
Checked Task Manager/Startup now both Disabled.

Comment: A screenshot might help us diagnose the issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my antivirus software (Avast) was the culprit. Have switched to an alternative product and that appears to have solved the problem so far.